# Why is my program reading more than just the first line of my txt file?

Tags: c++, file, io, ifstream, getline

I'm having trouble grabbing the first line of txtfile.txt. I've tried changing the number in the second parameter and completely removing it. Nothing has worked and for some reason I cannot grab the 1 alone.

```
int main() {
ifstream fin; 
char ex1[100];
fin.open("txtfile.txt");
if (fin.is_open()) {
    cout << "YES FILE OPENED" << endl; //testing if file opened
}
while (fin.peek() != EOF){
    fin.getline(ex1, 100, '\n');
    cout << ex1 << endl;
    }
}
```

**txtfile.txt: below**

```
1
ABC
2
```

Comment: What is the actual output? What is the desired output?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop

Comment: Why are you looping if you only want to read once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the first line, break from the while loop after getting the first line:

```
while (fin.peek() != EOF){
    fin.getline(ex1, 100, '\n');
    cout << ex1 << endl;
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason the '\n' doesn't work and the entire file prints out

Comment: try using fin.getline(ex1, 100). remove the '\n' delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int main()
    {
       ifstream fin; 
       char ex1[100];
       fin.open("txtfile.txt");
       if (fin)
       {        
          while (!fin.eof())
          {
             fin.getline(ex1, 100, '\n');
             cout << ex1 << endl;
          }
          fin.close();
       }
     }
```